# Smart way of simplifying logical circuits by hand?

Tags: logical-operators, boolean-logic, digital-logic, karnaugh-map

Let's say I have the following logical circuit:

[image]

How can I create a simplified version (assuming that one exists) without laboriously creating a truth table for it? I was thinking of perhaps writing the boolean expression as a sum of minterms to then create a Karnaugh map, but the expression that I get is unwieldy. Is there a better way?

Comment: There is no easy way. Truth table and Karnaugh map are helpful to derive a minimized two-level circuit. For multi-level circuits with multiple gate types, you might want to try [Logic Friday 1](https://logic-friday.software.informer.com/1.1/).